# Игнорирование событий мыши дочерним виджетом QT

Tags: qt, события, mousemove

Есть виджет с обработчиком событий мыши, на котором расположено представление. Обработчик получает события, когда мышь перемещается над виджетом. Когда мышь заходит на представление (которое в свою очередь находится на виджете), виджет должен продолжать получать события, несмотря на то, что мышь находится над представлением.

```
class Widget :public QWidget {
public:
    Widget() {
        setMouseTracking(true);
    }

    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * event) {
        qDebug() << event->x() << event->y();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    Widget widget;
    QListView view(&widget);
    view.setMouseTracking(true);
    widget.show();

    return app.exec(); 
}
```

В результате же, когда мышь над представлением, обработчик виджета не вызывается

Comment: попробуйте сделать вашему виджету `setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);`

Comment: @BeardedBeaver помогло. Только этот атрибут нужно ставить не виджету, а представлению

Comment: да, все верно. атрибут, как следует из имени атрибута, надо проставлять тому виджету, который должен игнорировать события мыши, передавая их своему родительскому (в плане лейаута) виджету

Comment: Для перехвата любых событий у любого объекта можно использовать механизм фильтра событий: [QObject::eventFilter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter).